# Return multiple tables specific to each column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get a more simple query that runs through all columns of a table and returns the SAME number of tables for EACH column.

For example...

```
select distinct a from tbl;
select distinct b from tbl;
select distinct c from tbl;
select distinct d from tbl;
```

would return four tables if ran at once. This gives the results I would like but I would have to type out each column, being especially pesky if I had many many columns. How can I write a query that would go through all the columns and give me the same results without having to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you would like each column from your table returned as a separate result? So if your table had 10 columns, you would have 10 result sets?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this without using some dynamic TSQL.  Are you able to execute dynamic code on your server?

Comment: Yes I am, I think that's the only option too but I'm inexperienced in that area

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comments, you are happy to use dynamic TSQL and you have permissions to execute it on your server.

Therefore, *one way* to achieve this is to enumerate the columns using a cursor and then execute some dynamic TSQL to get the result set for each column.

The following example shows how it can be done.  Simply modify `@table` to be the name of whichever table you want and it will output every column as a single result set:

```
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(50)
SET @table = 'tbl'

DECLARE curRead CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
  FOR
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table

OPEN curRead
FETCH NEXT FROM curRead INTO @column  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    SET @s = 'SELECT ' + @column + ' FROM ' + @table
    EXEC(@s)

    FETCH NEXT FROM curRead INTO @column 
END 
CLOSE curRead  
DEALLOCATE curRead
```

In this case, the CURSOR enumerates all of the columns that belong to your table.

You then iterate through these, storing the column name (from `COLUMN_NAME` in a variable `@column`), build a piece of dynamic SQL (is `@s`) and then execute it.

Comment: i just tested this and it says "commands completed successfully" but no output appears. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JosephYi It depends upon where you are running this code. Running in SQL Server Management Studio will output the tables as required.  If it's as a result set in an application then you may need to get the results into a DataSet.